# ProGuard is not applying the specified commands

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, proguard, android-proguard

I want to remove `Log` messages from signed APK. I am using pro-guard for this. Not much experience of pro-guard. I have followed a tutorial and did following.

This is what i added in app build.gradle file

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }

}
```

and i created this file in `app/` folder.

`proguard-rules.pro`

and added this code in this file

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}
```

But this is not removing any `Log` code  from the signed APK.

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: use this cmd -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; } . and instead of using proguard-android.txt use proguard-android-optimize.txt.

Comment: Thanks, should i create a new file for proguard-android-optimize.txt

Comment: I think this is default file that is already available in your project. The line you have commented just remove that one and make uncommented line commented.

Comment: Thanks, If i set `minifyEnabled false`. Will it work?  Because  `minifyEnabled true is giving warning messages.

Comment: what is the warning  you are getting?

Comment: If you set the minifyEnabled false then proguard will not work. It should be set to whatever you would have set runProguard to.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal : around 577 warnings :(

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal : can i disable obfuscate for all of the classes

Comment: yes, you can. If you don't want to use the proguard don't use it. If you want to use the proguard then use -keep class library_name

-dontwarn library_name. to ignore the warning.

Comment: I need to use proguard to disable log messages in production build, but i am unable to remove warnings. Thanks

Comment: so there is only one option. use progurad and use cmd --don'twarn libray_name.